# Error del servidor en proyecto Laravel subido al Cpanel

Tags: laravel

Subi mi app a un servidor de hosting y me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revise el log y es este error:

> C:\laragon\www\app\public\index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #45 {main}

El error corresponde a esta parte del codigo:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
```

Que puede ser provocar este error?

Comment: Primero revisa la configuración de PHP del servidor, versión, extensiones, etc. Que tienes el htaccess y en fichero .env bien configurados. Tendrías que indicar los pasos que has seguido al subir el proyecto para ver si el fallo es por algún descuido o algo incorrecto y no algo concreto de tu servidor. A parte de todo esto, la ruta: C:\laragon\www\app\public\index.php es local y de windows.

Comment: @Orici tienes razon. Ya solucione el problema y era que estaba copiando los datos de la app fuera de la carpeta que especifica el hosting que debe almacenar los archivos. Gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas veces es por cache `php artisan config:cache` o por las rutas `php artisan route:cache`

Para subir proyectos a Cpanel te sugiero seguir estas instrucciones https://www.nigmacode.com/laravel/Subir-proyecto-laravel-a-hosting/
lo puedes aplicar en cualquier versión de Laravel.